# Multi line plot in Altair - data formatting?

Tags: python, altair

How do I create a multi line plot in Altair?

In particular, I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
          Commit    Author  Date        Week    Adds   Deletes  Changes Files     
   0    cf6dc511bbf Dev 1   2019-03-18  12      0      0        0       0     
   1    6a96d05922f Dev 1   2019-03-18  12      504    0        504     5     
   2    0fbc7192380 Dev 1   2019-03-19  12      125    105      230     4    
   3    64a9c4a1fa0 Dev 1   2019-03-19  12      8      0        8       1
```

And would like to plot the Date vs Adds, Deletes and Changes on the same set of axes. How is that done? Do I need to reshape my data somehow?

The sample on the Altair website just includes a color, and it seems to be automatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to reshape your data, either as a preprocessing step in pandas, or using a [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html#fold-transform) available in Altair 3.0. There is information about working with this type of *wide-form data* in the documentation: [Altair: Long-form vs. Wide-form Data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Here's an example of using the transform-based approach with data similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', freq='D', periods=20),
    'Adds': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20),
    'Deletes': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20),
    'Changes': np.random.randint(0, 100, 20),
})

alt.Chart(df).transform_fold(
    ['Adds', 'Deletes', 'Changes']
).mark_bar().encode(
    x='yearmonthdate(Date):O',
    y='value:Q',
    color='key:N'
)
```

[image: chart]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the clear answer. BTW, I think I just watched a video of your Pycon talk? (Which what made me look at Altair in the first place).

Comment: No problem, I hope you find the library useful!